# Fallback to local config if Spring Vault config is disabled

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

For the development environment, I have configured `bootstrap.properties` to disable vault configuration.

```
spring.cloud.vault.enabled=false
```

If it is disabled then the application should read the properties from local config application.properties file. But how to do that?

As a workaround, I have defined the local properties in `application.properties` as below

```
xyz.db.user=${xyz.db.user.fromVault:test}
xyz.db.password=${xyz.db.password.fromVault:test}
```

So the application first checks if `xyz.db.user.fromVault` property is configured in vault. If not, then set `xyz.db.user` to `test`

But this doesn't feel like a right approach, as I need to maintain multiple properties. Is there any right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

It depends.

## Explanation

Providing fallback values for configuration properties is in general a good way to deal with defaults. If you have only a couple of these, then you can use this approach.

However, there's a caveat:

Data stored in Vault is somewhat depending on environments and typically sensitive (usernames, passwords). These aren't things you would like to store in your code or even in a properties file.

You could have a separate properties file (e.g. separated by profiles) that contains values for your non-Vault environment, but the actual question is, why you'd want to provide defaults at all?

If you have a remote database requiring credentials you'd might want to ask yourself the question: How much does it hurt if these credentials get exposed to unintended third parties? If your answer is: Not much, then storing these credentials in a profile-bound properties file is the way to go. If it hurts much, then I'd see two options:

1. Use Vault (which solves the actual issue of sensitive data)
2. Use a different approach (e.g. an in-memory database) that eliminates the need for credentials in the first place.

Comment: I found your [git site](https://github.com/mp911de/spring-cloud-vault-config-samples/blob/master/spring-cloud-vault/hello-world/src/test/java/example/helloworld/disabled/VaultConfigDisabledTests.java) detailing `"spring.cloud.vault.enabled=false"` that made the trick to disable for `test`. But couldn't make it work by adding this property to `application-test.yml`, is there a way to disable vault for `mvn test` goal without using the example way you created?